Why does TensorFlow function returning a symbolic error even when it is set to run eager mode
Following basic code which I am trying to debug for transformer implementation and I am facing this problem where tf.math.equal(seq, 0) return a symbolic tensor.
This only happens in this implementation while if I try a simple example it returns a eager tensor as expected.
Following is the train.py
# train.py

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import os
import pickle
import time
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode()
from transformer_implementation import Transformer


# Hyperparameters
NUM_LAYERS = 4
D_MODEL = 128
NUM_HEADS = 8
DFF = 512
DROPOUT_RATE = 0.1
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 20
MAX_LENGTH = 40


class CustomSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, d_model, warmup_steps=4000):
        super(CustomSchedule, self).__init__()

        self.d_model = tf.cast(d_model, tf.float32)
        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps

    def __call__(self, step):
        step = tf.cast(step, tf.float32)
        arg1 = tf.math.rsqrt(step)
        arg2 = step * (self.warmup_steps ** -1.5)

        return tf.math.rsqrt(self.d_model) * tf.math.minimum(arg1, arg2)


def load_dataset():
    # Load Portuguese-English translation dataset
    examples, metadata = tfds.load('ted_hrlr_translate/pt_to_en',
                                   with_info=True,
                                   as_supervised=True)
    train_examples, val_examples = examples['train'], examples['validation']

    return train_examples, val_examples, metadata


def get_or_create_tokenizer(text_data, vocab_size, tokenizer_path):
    if os.path.exists(tokenizer_path):
        print(f"Loading existing tokenizer from {tokenizer_path}")
        with open(tokenizer_path, 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)

    print("Creating new tokenizer...")
    tokenizer = tfds.deprecated.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
        text_data, target_vocab_size=vocab_size)

    # Save the tokenizer
    with open(tokenizer_path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(tokenizer, f)

    return tokenizer


def filter_max_length(pt, en):
    return tf.logical_and(tf.size(pt) <= MAX_LENGTH,
                          tf.size(en) <= MAX_LENGTH)


def prepare_dataset(examples):
    # Extract Portuguese and English text
    pt_texts = [ex[0].numpy().decode('utf-8') for ex in examples.take(1000)]  # Sample for tokenizer creation
    en_texts = [ex[1].numpy().decode('utf-8') for ex in examples.take(1000)]

    # Create or load tokenizers
    pt_tokenizer = get_or_create_tokenizer(pt_texts, 2 ** 13, 'pt_tokenizer.pkl')
    en_tokenizer = get_or_create_tokenizer(en_texts, 2 ** 13, 'en_tokenizer.pkl')

    def print_tokenizer_vocab_sizes(pt_tokenizer, en_tokenizer):
        print(f"Portuguese tokenizer vocabulary size: {pt_tokenizer.vocab_size}")
        print(f"English tokenizer vocabulary size: {en_tokenizer.vocab_size}")

    # Example usage
    print_tokenizer_vocab_sizes(pt_tokenizer, en_tokenizer)

    def encode(pt, en):
        pt = [pt_tokenizer.vocab_size] + pt_tokenizer.encode(
            pt.numpy()) + [pt_tokenizer.vocab_size + 1]
        en = [en_tokenizer.vocab_size] + en_tokenizer.encode(
            en.numpy()) + [en_tokenizer.vocab_size + 1]
        return pt, en

    def tf_encode(pt, en):
        return tf.py_function(encode, [pt, en], [tf.int64, tf.int64])

    dataset = (examples
               .map(tf_encode, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
               .filter(filter_max_length)
               .cache()
               .shuffle(20000)
               .padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes=([None], [None]))
               .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE))

    return dataset, pt_tokenizer, en_tokenizer


def loss_function(real, pred):
    mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
    loss_ = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(real, pred, from_logits=True)

    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
    loss_ *= mask

    return tf.reduce_mean(loss_)


def train_step(transformer, optimizer, inp, tar):
    tar_inp = tar[:, :-1]
    tar_real = tar[:, 1:]

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = transformer([inp, tar_inp], training=True)
        loss = loss_function(tar_real, predictions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, transformer.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, transformer.trainable_variables))

    return loss


def main():

    # Load and prepare datasets
    train_examples, val_examples, metadata = load_dataset()
    train_dataset, pt_tokenizer, en_tokenizer = prepare_dataset(train_examples)
    val_dataset, _, _ = prepare_dataset(val_examples)

    # Initialize model
    input_vocab_size = pt_tokenizer.vocab_size + 2  # Add 2 for start and end tokens
    target_vocab_size = en_tokenizer.vocab_size + 2

    transformer = Transformer(
        num_layers=NUM_LAYERS,
        d_model=D_MODEL,
        num_heads=NUM_HEADS,
        dff=DFF,
        input_vocab_size=input_vocab_size,
        target_vocab_size=target_vocab_size,
        pe_input=MAX_LENGTH,
        pe_target=MAX_LENGTH,
        rate=DROPOUT_RATE)

    # Initialize optimizer
    learning_rate = CustomSchedule(D_MODEL)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98, epsilon=1e-9)

    # Checkpointing
    checkpoint_path = "./checkpoints/train"
    ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(transformer=transformer, optimizer=optimizer)
    ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, checkpoint_path, max_to_keep=5)

    if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
        ckpt.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
        print('Latest checkpoint restored!!')

    # Training loop
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        start = time.time()
        train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')

        for (batch, (inp, tar)) in enumerate(train_dataset):
            batch_loss = train_step(transformer, optimizer, inp, tar)
            train_loss(batch_loss)

            if batch % 100 == 0:
                print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} Batch {batch} Loss {batch_loss:.4f}')

        if (epoch + 1) % 5 == 0:
            ckpt_save_path = ckpt_manager.save()
            print(f'Saving checkpoint for epoch {epoch + 1} at {ckpt_save_path}')

        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1} Loss {train_loss.result():.4f}')
        print(f'Time taken for 1 epoch: {time.time() - start:.2f} secs\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
    main()

Following is the transformer implementation
# transformer.py

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class MultiHeadAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
        super(MultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.d_model = d_model

        assert d_model % num_heads == 0

        self.depth = d_model // num_heads

        self.wq = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.wk = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        self.wv = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)

        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)

    def split_heads(self, x, batch_size):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, -1, self.num_heads, self.depth))
        return tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])

    def call(self, v, k, q, mask=None):
        batch_size = tf.shape(q)[0]

        q = self.wq(q)
        k = self.wk(k)
        v = self.wv(v)

        q = self.split_heads(q, batch_size)
        k = self.split_heads(k, batch_size)
        v = self.split_heads(v, batch_size)

        scaled_attention = scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, mask)

        scaled_attention = tf.transpose(scaled_attention, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])
        concat_attention = tf.reshape(scaled_attention, (batch_size, -1, self.d_model))

        output = self.dense(concat_attention)
        return output

def scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, mask=None):
    matmul_qk = tf.matmul(q, k, transpose_b=True)
    dk = tf.cast(tf.shape(k)[-1], tf.float32)
    scaled_attention_logits = matmul_qk / tf.math.sqrt(dk)

    if mask is not None:
        scaled_attention_logits += (mask * -1e9)

    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_attention_logits, axis=-1)
    output = tf.matmul(attention_weights, v)
    return output

class PositionalEncoding(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, position, d_model):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.pos_encoding = self.positional_encoding(position, d_model)

    def get_angles(self, position, i, d_model):
        angles = 1 / np.power(10000, (2 * (i//2)) / np.float32(d_model))
        return position * angles

    def positional_encoding(self, position, d_model):
        angle_rads = self.get_angles(
            position=np.arange(position)[:, np.newaxis],
            i=np.arange(d_model)[np.newaxis, :],
            d_model=d_model)

        angle_rads[:, 0::2] = np.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])
        angle_rads[:, 1::2] = np.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])

        pos_encoding = angle_rads[np.newaxis, ...]
        return tf.cast(pos_encoding, dtype=tf.float32)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs + self.pos_encoding[:, :tf.shape(inputs)[1], :]

class EncoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, dff, rate=0.1):
        super(EncoderLayer, self).__init__()

        self.mha = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.ffn = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(dff, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        ])

        self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)

        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, training, mask=None):
        attn_output = self.mha(x, x, x, mask)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(x + attn_output)

        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        out2 = self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)

        return out2

class DecoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, dff, rate=0.1):
        super(DecoderLayer, self).__init__()

        self.mha1 = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)
        self.mha2 = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads)

        self.ffn = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(dff, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model)
        ])

        self.layernorm1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm3 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)

        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask=None, padding_mask=None):
        attn1 = self.mha1(x, x, x, look_ahead_mask)
        attn1 = self.dropout1(attn1, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(attn1 + x)

        attn2 = self.mha2(enc_output, enc_output, out1, padding_mask)
        attn2 = self.dropout2(attn2, training=training)
        out2 = self.layernorm2(attn2 + out1)

        ffn_output = self.ffn(out2)
        ffn_output = self.dropout3(ffn_output, training=training)
        out3 = self.layernorm3(ffn_output + out2)

        return out3

class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, input_vocab_size,
                 target_vocab_size, pe_input, pe_target, rate=0.1):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = Encoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff,
                             input_vocab_size, pe_input, rate)

        self.decoder = Decoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff,
                             target_vocab_size, pe_target, rate)

        self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_vocab_size)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        inp, tar = inputs

        enc_padding_mask = create_padding_mask(inp)
        look_ahead_mask = create_look_ahead_mask(tf.shape(tar)[1])
        dec_padding_mask = create_padding_mask(inp)

        enc_output = self.encoder(inp, training, enc_padding_mask)
        dec_output = self.decoder(tar, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask)

        final_output = self.final_layer(dec_output)
        return final_output

class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, input_vocab_size,
                 maximum_position_encoding, rate=0.1):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_vocab_size, d_model)
        self.pos_encoding = PositionalEncoding(maximum_position_encoding, d_model)

        self.enc_layers = [EncoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, dff, rate)
                          for _ in range(num_layers)]

        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, training, mask=None):
        seq_len = tf.shape(x)[1]

        x = self.embedding(x)
        x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
        x = self.pos_encoding(x)

        x = self.dropout(x, training=training)

        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            x = self.enc_layers[i](x, training, mask)

        return x

class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, target_vocab_size,
                 maximum_position_encoding, rate=0.1):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(target_vocab_size, d_model)
        self.pos_encoding = PositionalEncoding(maximum_position_encoding, d_model)

        self.dec_layers = [DecoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, dff, rate)
                          for _ in range(num_layers)]
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, x, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask=None, padding_mask=None):
        seq_len = tf.shape(x)[1]

        x = self.embedding(x)
        x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
        x = self.pos_encoding(x)

        x = self.dropout(x, training=training)

        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            x = self.dec_layers[i](x, enc_output, training,
                                 look_ahead_mask, padding_mask)

        return x

def create_padding_mask(seq):
    mask = tf.cast(tf.math.equal(seq, 0), tf.float32)
    return mask[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]

def create_look_ahead_mask(size):
    mask = 1 - tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((size, size)), -1, 0)
    return mask

The symbolic tensor is returned by tf.math.equal(seq, 0) in create_padding_mask function in transformer implementation code and input seq is a eager tensor. Any reason why this function is not returning this eager tensor as expected?
